# NSDictionary Memory leaks

Tags: iphone, memory-leaks, nsdictionary

I implement a method to return a dictionary in my app. But I find a memory leak using instrument, I tried to figure it out, but I still cannot find it. Can anyone help me out?

Thanks in advance, here is the code for that methods:

```
-(NSMutableDictionary *)initDict
{
    NSMutableDictionary *dict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
    [dict setObject:self.name forKey:@"Name"];
    //Some similar set object for key here...
    return dict;
}
```

I think the problem is from allocing memory for dict and not releasing it. But in the method, it seems I cannot release dict. So is there any method to fix the leak?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All variants are good. Here is third variant (choose wisely):

Replace

```
NSMutableDictionary *dict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
```

with

```
NSMutableDictionary *dict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
```

Comment: `dictionary]` is a synonym for `init] autorelease]`; you should probably use this version above explicit `autorelease` calls because the object is created in the same scope it's returned/autoreleased, which is the intended use case of the `dictionary]` initialiser (a temporary object).

Comment: you have solved the last of my 50 memory leaks thank you. I never knew about this and I thank you greatly for this. I think this needs to be upvoted a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to change the last line of `initDict` to this:

```
return [dict autorelease];
```

Comment: +1 This is useful if the object is initialised in the same scope but is passed elsewhere before the `return` statement, and there's a danger of it being in an `NSAutoreleasePool` which is `drain`ed, thereby deallocating it. This *shouldn't* be a problem, because autorelease pools are stacked to avoid that kind of deallocation problem, but there's probably an edge case I can't think of right now where you have to be sure it's properly `retain`ed.

Answer (score 0):

When you are creating any object in your function and you want to return them then you should always create it in a way that those objects are autoreleased. So you should change your code like below.

```
NSMutableDictionary *dict = [[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init]autorelease];
```

So whenever you create any object just call autorelease method on that.